# Como pasar filas de un datatable a un array?

Tags: c#

Tengo dos datatable(uno con cod de comprobantes y otro con cod asientos) del cual tengo que ir fila a fila procesando los datos (de ambos dt a la vez) y para eso necesito copiar la fila de de cada dt a un array y estaba usando el siguiente codigo:

```
 int[] aux1;
 int[] aux2;


        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow ex in dtComprobantes.Rows)               
            {
                DataRow[] dr = dtComprobantes.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
                object[] dr1 = dr[0].ItemArray;
                aux1 = Array.ConvertAll(dr1, p => Convert.ToInt32(p));

                DataRow[] dr2 = dtAsientos.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
                object[] dr3 = dr2[0].ItemArray;
                aux2 = Array.ConvertAll(dr3, p => Convert.ToInt32(p));

                cod_comprobantes = aux1;
                cod_asientos = aux2;
                .
                .
                .
                //continua con el procesamiento de los array
```

El problema es que si el dt tiene 6 filas repite 6 veces el proceso solo con los datos de la primera fila, asi que lo cambie a

```
  int[] aux1;
  int[] aux2;


        try
        {
            //foreach (DataRow ex in dtComprobantes.Rows)
            for (int q = 0; q < dtComprobantes.Rows.Count; q++)
            {
                DataRow[] dr = dtComprobantes.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
                object[] dr1 = dr[q].ItemArray;
                aux1 = Array.ConvertAll(dr1, p => Convert.ToInt32(p));

                DataRow[] dr2 = dtAsientos.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
                object[] dr3 = dr2[q].ItemArray;
                aux2 = Array.ConvertAll(dr3, p => Convert.ToInt32(p));

                cod_comprobantes = aux1;
                cod_asientos = aux2;
                .
                .
                .
                //continua con el procesamiento de los array
```

pero cunado el contador cambia a 1 me sale una excepción que dice "indice fuera de los rangos de la matriz"

como puedo arreglar este error o como puedo pasar la fila a un array ?

de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Primero, pusiste imagenes. Imposible ayudarte con imagenes, pone el codigo. Segundo, porque haces esto? tu codigo ya pasa todo el datatable a un array si queres, sin iterar ni hacer un for, al hacer ToArray!!!!! igual tampoco me queda claro porque queres pasarlos a un array, si el datatable tambien se puede recorrer....

Comment: Comparte tu código con formato de código y elimina las imágenes.

Comment: @gbianchi , lo que pasa que toda la validación de los dato se hace mediante arreglos, por eso tengo  que pasar cada fila a un arreglo para hacer la validación.

Comment: eh? no se que tiene que ver.. un arreglo.. una lista.. un iterable, son basicamente lo mismo... igual, ya te dije, tu codigo ya pasa un dt a un array en la primer line.. si sacas el take, se soluciona todo...